# How to get current post id in Gutenberg custom block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

This is my block.js file. In 4th line, I have MediaUpload var, Under it I want current post id. How can I get it?

```
( function( blocks, editor, i18n, element, components, _ ) {
var el = element.createElement;
var RichText = editor.RichText;
var MediaUpload = editor.MediaUpload;

blocks.registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-05-recipe-card', {
    title: i18n.__( 'Author card', 'gutenberg-examples' ),
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        writer: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'h2',
        },
        photography: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'h2',
        },
```

Answer (score 5):

The current postId is accessed by the [block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) by adding `usesContext` when registering the block type, eg:

```
blocks.registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-05-recipe-card', {
    title: i18n.__( 'Author card', 'gutenberg-examples' ),
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {...},
    usesContext: [ 'postId' ]
});
```

By including **context** in your `edit({attributes, setAttributes, context})` function, you will have access to the current postId with:

```
edit({attributes, setAttributes, context}){    
    const {postId} = context;
}
```

Comment: I will check it

Comment: How about the save function?